# Unable to retrieve correct results

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I had a question regarding a SQL script that i am working on

```
SELECT distinct companyid, 
       companyshortname, 
       loanamount, 
       employeename, 
       , employeerole, 
       MaxTime, 
       businessdescription
FROM       company
INNER JOIN loan ON companyfkey = loanfkey
LEFT JOIN (SELECT businessdescription_fkey, 
                  MAX(w.business_date_transaction_occured) AS MaxTime 
           FROM businessdescription w
           WHERE w.businessstatus <> 3    <-- this means that the company is still open
           GROUP BY w.businessdescription_fkey) wf 
ON company_fkey = businessdescriotion_fkey
```

This will return to me all businesses that have a status that is different than 3 , however my first issue is that its returning to me all business that do have the status of 3.

My second question is how would i incorporate another value to trace such as Businessdescriptioncomment  would i do something like this?

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT businessdescription_fkey, 
                  MAX(w.business_date_transaction_occured) AS MaxTime ,
                  w.businessdescriptioncomment AS BusinessComment
           FROM   businessdescription w         
           WHERE  w.businessstatus <> 3 <-- this means that the company is open
           GROUP BY w.businessdescription_fkey) wf 
ON company_fkey = businessdescriotion_fkey
```

and my variable BusinessComment to my first select?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you check you inner select? 
does it just return rows with business = 3?

if so, maybe change the LEFT join to an INNER join

Comment: There is a double `,` here: `employeename, , employeerole,`

Comment: Your question is not  ... clear  .. you have errror?  ... wrong result  ...?  ..

Comment: mysql <> sql server. Please add back the tag of the DBMS you are actually using.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Left Join` use Inner Join as it will only give records where company if open. Also, I have used `self join` in Sub query to get `Business Comment`and then used it in outer select query

Try this:-

```
SELECT distinct companyid, 
       companyshortname, 
       loanamount, 
       employeename, 
       , employeerole, 
       MaxTime, 
       businessdescription,
       BusinessComment
FROM       company a

INNER JOIN loan b
ON a.companyfkey = b.loanfkey

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.businessdescription_fkey, a.MaxTime, w.businessdescriptioncomment AS BusinessComment
    FROM
    (
    SELECT businessdescription_fkey, 
                      MAX(w.business_date_transaction_occured) AS MaxTime 
               FROM   businessdescription w         
               WHERE  w.businessstatus <> 3 
               GROUP BY w.businessdescription_fkey
    ) a
    INNER JOIN
    businessdescription w
    ON a.businessdescription_fkey=w.businessdescription_fkey AND a.MaxTime=w.business_date_transaction_occured
    WHERE  w.businessstatus <> 3 
) c
ON a.company_fkey = c.businessdescriotion_fkey
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: @ artbarzz you are welcome. Happy to help. You can accept if you liked the solution. Please visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more info

Answer (score 0):

Change your 2nd join like this:

```
INNER JOIN businessdescription w 
ON company_fkey = w.businessdescriotion_fkey 
and businessstatus <> 3
```

In your select put:

```
SELECT distinct companyid, 
         companyshortname, 
         loanamount, 
         employeename, 
         employeerole, 
         MaxTime, 
         businessdescription,
         w.businessdescriptioncomment
FROM  company
```

Tell me if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

In your JOIN sub query, you have added the filter *businessstatus <> 3* to exclude id 3. But that's a LEFT JOIN. In that case, it will bring everything from the first table, in your case company and load.

Replace LEFT JOIN with INNER JOIN.

Do you have any other valid reason for LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have give a where condition(businessstatus <> 3) on the sub query, it only filters the subquery, so if you do the Left join with subquery, it returns the result of left table plus right table with some row showing Null columns (in this case (businessstatus == 3 would be Null)

Using Inner join instead of left join can give the result of bussinessstatus <> 3